# Adding CSS file in ADF JSF page

Tags: css, jsf, oracle-adf

I have created jsf page

```
<f:view>

 <af:document id="d1">
   <f:facet name="metaContainer">
   <af:resource type="css">
     af|inputText :: content
     {
     color:Red;
     }
</af:resource>
  </f:facet>


 <af:form id="f1">
  <af:panelHeader text="Customer" id="ph1">

    <af:selectOneRadio label="Gender"
                       requiredMessageDetail="Must Provide Gender"
                       id="sor1" layout="horizontal"
                       value="#{CustomerBean.gender}" autoSubmit="true">
      <af:selectItem label="Female" value="F" id="si1"/>
      <af:selectItem label="Male" value="M" id="si2"/>
    </af:selectOneRadio>
  </af:panelHeader>
  <af:inputText label="FirstName" id="it1" value="#{CustomerBean.first}"/>
  <af:inputText label="LastName" id="it2" value="#{CustomerBean.last}"/>
  <af:outputText id="ot1"
                 partialTriggers="sor1" value="#{CustomerBean.gender}"/>
</af:form>
```

I want to apply Red color to all the inputText I am using. We can perform it using CSS. But I am not able to get any output from it. I have also tried

```
 <f:facet name="metaContainer">
  <af:resource type="css">
     .text-label
     {
     color:Red;
     }
  </af:resource>
  </f:facet>
```

Another way I tried is :

```
 <f:facet name="metaContainer">
     <af:resource type="css">
      [id=form\:inputText]{
       color: Red;
      }
     </af:resource>
```

But it's not working. Please suggest me the proper way to use CSS code in JSF page in ADF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use CSS directly in an ADF Faces page, because the components that you use in ADF Faces generate multiple HTML elements. You use Skins.
See this [video](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/adf-insider-skinning/adf-insider-skinning.html) to get started. And [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/index-092146.html) and [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/b31973/af_skin.htm). Reading the docs for a new framework is generally a good idea ;-)

You don't say what version you're on - that info helps us help you - but most recent versions have a [skin editor](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/skineditor/install-skin-editor/toc.htm) built to into JDeveloper or downloadable.

Use the [Skin Selectors](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/skin-selectors.html) to set style for the components and sub-components.

Skin files generate the correct CSS file when the page is gen'd and downloaded with the page.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to make it red.

1. Using `inlineStyle`
2. Using `styleClass`

You can choose anyone. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes I am trying inlineStyle in ADF using af:resource type tag, but it's not working.

Comment: <af:inputText label="FirstName" id="it1" labelStyle="color:Red; font-weight:bold;"/> use it...Hope it works for you..

Comment: yes But I have to do this to each and every inputText. Can't we use in adf like we use in html eg: <script type = "css"> .text-label { color: red} </script>

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-cascading-style-sheets-css-in-jsf/ Check this link...Hope it will clear your conception...

Comment: Actually, these are for one-offs when you want to override the Skin, not first choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `inlineStyle` tag in the adf faces such as panelbox.

For example
`inlineStyle="margin-left: 25px;"`